# pagerank implementation in java

Tags: java, jung

I am looking for a java implementation of the pagerank algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Well you've tagged this question with JUNG which includes an implementation of the PageRank algorithm. Here's a link to the [Javadoc](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/importance/PageRank.html) for it if you haven't seen it. You can get the source for [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) easily.

You could also take a look at the [WebLA](http://webla.sourceforge.net/) project on sourceforge. The have a Java implementation of [PageRank](http://webla.sourceforge.net/javadocs/).