# Can any one tell me how to create an graph for JUNG for page rank

Tags: jung, pagerank

I am just trying to implement page rank for my small network and i gone though some answers from these questions.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353898/pagerank-implementation-in-java
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784530/pagerank-implementation-in-java
```

JUNG is an web-graph library that implements pagerank . But i haven't seen any example how to compute the graph . can any one please explain it with an example.

Comment: Have you checked this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757262/how-to-use-pagerank-algorithm-in-jung)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

- https://github.com/castagna/mr-pagerank/blob/3b0f11cc5e3aab392769c7e4b0e6bed149cfbf11/src/main/java/com/talis/labs/pagerank/jung/JungPageRank.java
- https://github.com/castagna/mr-pagerank/blob/3b0f11cc5e3aab392769c7e4b0e6bed149cfbf11/src/main/java/com/talis/labs/pagerank/memory/PlainPageRank.java

You do not need to use JUNG, if you want you have write your own implementation (as PlainPageRank above).